# Scala nested collection assignment

Tags: scala, collections

I'm trying to build a mutable map from integers to a mutable set of integers in Scala.

For example, I would like to have the mappings of the form 1 -> (2,3) and be able to update
them later using the key value. The code that I use is as follows:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

val map = Map[Int, Set[Int]]()
map: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]] = Map()

map += (1 -> Set(2,3))
res15: map.type = Map(1 -> Set(2, 3))
```

So far good, but when I try to do something like

```
map.get(1) += 4
```

I get an assignment to val error. What is confusing to me is that map.get() should return a 
Set of type scala.collection.mutable.Set which can be updated. Can someone please shed some
light what's going on here?

Comment: You should accept some of the answers to your questions, btw :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in this case is that `get()` returns an option (`Option[scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]]`), which you need to "unpack":

```
map.get(1).get += 4
```

The reason Map's `get()` function returns an option is that there might not be a value for any given key, and Scala does not like throwing exceptions like its Java API counterpart.

Alternatively you could use the `apply()` method, which directly returns the requested value and throws an exception in case of failure:

```
map(1) += 4
```

---

I haven't quite figured out why you'd get a "reassignment to val" error with the code you've tried, though. In my case (Scala 2.10), it says the following:

```
<console>:12: error: value += is not a member of Option[scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]]
          map.get(1) += 1
```

Which version of Scala are you using?

Comment: Thanks! great answer. I'm on 2.9.2. Now I also have a good reason to upgrade.

Comment: Another question related to my previous one:

if I define the collection as var map = Map[Int, Set[Int]](),
this time with immutable collections but a var, again I get the error 
reassignment to val (I'm still on scala 2.9.2) when I try something like map(1) += 4. I think that's because Set[Int] is immutable.

Do you know any workarounds for this case?

Comment: `Seq` doesn't even have a `+=` method. In any case, you won't be able to add anything to an immutable data structure, and if you'd find a way to do it, that would be a bug and should be fixed as soon as possible, given that in many cases, when using immutable data structures, you _rely_ on them being immutable.

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained in a misleading way. The better of asking is that how can I create a new Map[Int, Set[Int]] from an existing one, apply my changes and put the results back to the defined variable. If I don't have nested collections, it's OK, for example:

`var map = Map((1->3),(2->3),(3->4))` and then `map += (2->4)` the result would be `scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 4)`  Here, Scala creates a new copy for me with changes applied. But when I have the nested Set inside it doesn't work. Is it more clear now?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to achieve what I explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447242/how-to-modify-a-value-of-a-map-which-contains-sets-returning-a-new-map/14447243#14447243).

Comment: Yes, that works :) I however needed to add the default case to avoid Match exceptions. `x.map { case (1, v) => (1, v + 5) case x@_ => x }`

Answer (score 0):

more elegant way is

```
map.get(1).map(_ += 4).getOrElse{map += 1 -> Seq(4)}
```